# SwiftUI Keyboard Toolbar not Showing

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield, toolbar

I have a TextField for commenting but it cannot be dismissed due to the tool bar not showing on the keyboard. Previously there was a tool bar with a `done` button but it is not showing anymore, not sure what happened to it.

The TextField is in a VStack/SrollView placed at the very bottom of the screen (similar to iMessage)

Is there a reason it has disappeared? is it a device setting that might have changed?

```
        TextField("comment...", text: $textToPost)
            .keyboardType(.alphabet)
            .padding(.leading, 20)
            .lineLimit(0)
            .focused($focusField, equals: .comment)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
@State private var commentText = ""
@FocusState private var commentTextFieldFocus

TextField("Comment...", text: $commentText)
    .keyboardType(.alphabet)
    .padding(.leading, 20)
    .lineLimit(0)
    .focused($commentTextFieldFocus)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Button("Done") {
                commentTextFieldFocus = false
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: Can you elaborate? What exactly did you do? This should work